# Vertical scroll table body inside bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, scroll, html-table

I'm using bootstrap3 modal and trying to create a table inside a modal.
I want the tbody to have vertical scroll. I've tried adding the height and overflow-y: auto to tbody, but it won't work.

I was able to have the entire modal scrollable, but I just want only the table body to be scrollable

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Sorry, deleted my answer...

Comment: That's ok. I'm actually trying to modify your answer. Still no hope.
But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found an answer for this.

I adapted the code from here: http://jsfiddle.net/T9Bhm/7/

The CSS Solution:

```
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }

    tr:after {
        content: ' ';
        display: block;
        visibility: hidden;
        clear: both;
    }

    thead th {
        height: 30px;

        /*text-align: left;*/
    }

    tbody {
        height: 120px;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

    thead {
        /* fallback */
    }


    tbody td, thead th {
        width: 19.2%;
        float: left;
    }
```