# Table can be scrolled inside bootstrap modal but now table entries width aren't same

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to make a table body scrollable inside a modal while table headers are sticky.

I searched in stackoverflow about this and saw related questions to this issue, however, all of them couldn't solve my problem.

According to [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187913/vertical-scroll-table-body-inside-bootstrap-modal), I wrote this code

CSS:

```
body .modal-dialog {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto !important;
    display: inline-block;
}

.modal {
    z-index: -1;
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.modal-open .modal {
    z-index: 1050;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
}

thead,
tbody,
tr,
td,
th {
    display: block;
}

tr:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

thead th {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

tbody {
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

thead th {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}

tbody td {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Modal1" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="table-wrapper">
                    <table class="table table-hover" style="width: 100%;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Col1</th>
                                <th scope="col">Col2</th>
                                <th scope="col">Col3</th>
                                <th scope="col">Col4</th>
                                <th scope="col">Col5</th>
                                <th scope="col">Col6</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="table-light">
                                <td>5875</td>
                                <td>Eewrwerwerwer</td>
                                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Button1</button></td>
                                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Button2</button></td>
                                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Button3</button></td>
                                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Button4</button></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-light">
                                <td>1366</td>
                                <td>Eewrwerwerwasdasdasdsaderwerwer</td>
                                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Button1</button></td>
                                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Button2</button></td>
                                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Button3</button></td>
                                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Button4</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the table body is scrollable and table header is sticky, but unfortunately their width aren't same:

[Look at this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyPJv.png)

**Update:**
One of the solutions I think may be useful (I didn't try that!) is finding maximum width of every column at table and then change width of columns dynamically by JavaScript, however, I think there should be a CSS solution for that...

**Update 2:**
An other solution that I think may be work is placing table header inside modal header and placing table body inside modal body and using table-responsive class. but I don't know how to separate table header and body inside different div(s)?